# Weird Solr Indexing changing automatically

Tags: solr

I am using solr for indexing the documents. I have an old hander and now i am changing the handler with new ranking equation.

As a part of testing, i have written a python scripts which uses urllib2 to hit SolrURL and get the data in JSON format.

What I am observing each time i run this python script, the indexing for the query automatically changes. This is kind of weird and I am not getting why is this happening.

Kindly help
Thanks

Comment: What type of changes you are observing? Is it the number of results getting changed or the order of result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you need to sort your result by **score** while querying.
2. In a certain time interval **optimize** your Solr nodes.

Though Solr optimizes implicitely, but I prefer doing this explicitly. Hope these will help you to get your order of result same every time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the queryResultCache is on and for different SearchHandler, i have the same equation, so i was getting the same results for different handler.

Now I have one handler where the handling of query is broken. My query ends with %0A and it was not handled properly and the results (which were incorrect) were being cached.

I fix the handling of query and it resolved the issue.